# Trying to check for time above 9am in php but wont take any thing above 10?

Tags: php

I'm simply trying to check if the time is either above 9am or below 6pm, the 6pm check works fine and displays the data where as 9am one does nothing but works when changed to 10am.

Here is the line of code I'm using

```
elseif ((($data[6]) < "09:00") || (($data[6]) > "18:00"))
             {
             $contact[] = $data;
             }
```

Comment: Can you specify what `$data[6]` could contain? The same format would make sense, something like `11:22`?

Comment: You are using OR ...use &&. Otherwise in every case, your condition will be true. Because 7 AM is lower than 6 PM. Here in your code it should be checked that if time is greater than 9 and smaller than 6 pm...so use && operator

Comment: Using `>` and `<` with strings may not work the way you think it does.  PHP will convert the strings to numbers and then compare them.  Converting `"18:36"` to a number will result in just `18`.

Comment: So the code is reading in a csv file with booking slots that contain customer info and $data[6] is the time column containing time in the format of hh:mm @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Tried that already and get no output at all then @ShivamShukla

Comment: So if you are reading it in hh:mm how will php evaluate it as number.

Comment: You are currently comparing strings. Now this probably would work, if you get the logic right, but I think it would be better to work with numbers. I would convert the times to integers using something like [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime). (this will create a timestamp for that time today)

Comment: The time you are comparing and from which it is getting compared both should be in number, and also use && operator not || operator. Otherwise you will always get your condition be true.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I would probably prefer [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) since you can customize the format.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I agree, but that's more complex. Alternatively you could create a function to convert the time string to the number of minutes. Something like this: `$minuteOfDay = 60 * strstr($time, ':', TRUE) + substr(strstr($time, ':'), 1);`

Answer (score 0):

So, let us assume that your time format is always **hh:mm**. You want to check if the time is between 9 and 18 hours. The problem in your code, as you described, comes when you are check again **09:mm**. As it strips away the minute part and just compares the hours.

I would try something like this:

`elseif ( implode("", explode(":", $data[6])) > 900 && implode("", explode(":", $data[6])) < 1800)`

I will explain the approach step by step.

1. First of all, this code checks if the date is within the range of 09:00 to 18:00. The code you have provided tested if it is less than 9 or more than 18.
2. Let us focus on one part of the code, that will explain the whole thing as well:

   `implode("", explode(":", $data[6])) > 900`

First, we separate hours and minutes using the `explode` function. This gives us an array with two values.

```
`[0] => hh,`
`[1] => mm`
```

Now that we have separated this value we implode or concatenate them using the `implode` function that has no separator.

Next, instead of testing against the string, we test against the number. **09:00** is the same as **900** in this case.

Thus, we can check if the time is within the required limits.